# Converting isotime to shorttime in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ajax call which returns a time  e.g  16:06:59 i want to convert it to  4:06 PM

```
 var mydate = obj[0].time;
```

`mydate`  comes 16:06:59   but when i try to use it with  `var date = new Date()`, it gives me todays date .

Is there any solution to realize what i want  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
function Convert24HoursTo12(time) {
  var timeArray = time.split(':');
  var hours = timeArray[0]; 
  var minutes = timeArray[1];
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return strTime;
}
```

and call it:

```
Convert24HoursTo12(obj[0].time);
```

[See Demo Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/vPxdL/)

Comment: I tested 10 min. ago and it gave me  4:006 pm but now it gives me 4:06 pm but there is no change in the script right ?

Comment: Can we also put extra 0 ,   like 04:05 PM

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is to split it into parts and then use them however you want, e.g.:

```
var parts = obj[0].time.split(":");
// parts[0] is now "16"
// parts[1] is now "06"
// parts[2] is now "59"
// Then perhaps (to get numbers and give the parts names)
var hours = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
var minutes = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
var seconds = parseInt(parts[2], 10);
```

...and of course for the first one you can use:

```
if (hours > 12) {
    hours -= 12;
}
```

...if you want to do the a.m./p.m. thing. Just remember you did that and set your a.m./p.m. variable accordingly.

If you really want a `Date` instance, you can do this:

```
var dt = new Date();
dt.setHours(hours); // Be sure to use the real value here, not the one -12
dt.setMinutes(minutes);
dt.setSeconds(seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
"16:06:59".split(':').slice(0, 2)
    .map(function (x, index) {
    return index == 0 ? (x > 12 ? x - 12 + "PM" : x + "AM") : x
}).join(":").replace(/(.+?)((P|A)M)(.+)/, "$1$4 $2");
```

Comment: Why would you use `.map()` with a conditional to only actually operate on the first item in the array? And where is the "AM" or "PM" at the end of the resulting string?

Comment: Because, 16 is the first element, which I'm gonna convert to 4, the next part is okay. You don't need to do something with it, so just return it

Comment: I understand how your code works, I'm just saying that using `.map()` and iterating over the _whole_ array when you know you want to modify only the first element is a bit clunky. `var d = "16:06:59".split(":"); if (d[0]>12) d[0]-=12; d = d.join(":");` does the same thing in a more straightforward and efficient manner...

Comment: @nnnnnn, I'm splitting it up, and taking just first two elements using slice, and map() it. Now I've added PM, AM as well

Comment: it's like using a "fire truck" where you could just use a "fire extinguisher"... that's the point of @nnnnnn

Comment: @Reigel, so am I doing it wrong? How can I improve it?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the following code according to your need

```
var mydate= new Date();
var myhour=mydate.getHours();
var ampm="AM";
if(myhour==12)ampm="PM";
if(myhour==0)myhour=12;
if (myhour>12){
    myhour-=12;
    ampm="PM";
}else{
    myhour=mydate.getHours();
}
var mytime=myhour+":"+mydate.getMinutes()+":"+mydate.getSeconds()+" "+ampm;
```

then use mytime variable anywhere you want

I have not checked it as I am in  a hurry now. I hope it works well.